# Authenticating user with LDAP from PHP with only SamAccountName and Password?

Tags: php, ldap

how can I authenticate from PHP using LDAP when I only have the SamAccountName and Password?  Is there a way to bind with just SamAccountName and Password and without Distinguished Name.  The only examples I have found assume you have the DN:

```
$server="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
$dn = "cn=$username, "; 
$basedn="ou=users, ou=accounts, dc=domain, dc=com";

if (!($connect = ldap_connect($server))) { 
   die ("Could not connect to LDAP server"); 
} 

if (!($bind = ldap_bind($connect, "$dn" . "$basedn", $password))) {        
   die ("Could not bind to $dn"); 
} 

$sr = ldap_search($connect, $basedn,"$filter"); 
$info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $sr); 
$fullname=$info[0]["displayname"][0]; 
$fqdn=$info[0]["dn"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the answer is that it depends on how the LDAP server was configured by the admin.  You don't always need a DN to authenticate to an LDAP server.  In my particular case, even with the DN, I still couldn't authenticate to the LDAP server.  For the LDAP server I was trying to connect, it appears it was a Microsoft Domain, and so I could only authenticate with DOMAIN\user015 for user015 in DOMAIN where user015 is a SamAccountName and DOMAIN is the domain for that user.  But I was able to authenticate.

Thank you for all the posts!  Even if they weren't the correct answer, they did help a lot!

Answer (score 20):

This works for me. I spent many a days trying to figure this one out.

```
<?php

//We just need six varaiables here
$baseDN = 'CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local';
$adminDN = "YourAdminDN";//this is the admin distinguishedName
$adminPswd = "YourAdminPass";
$username = 'Username';//this is the user samaccountname
$userpass = 'UserPass';
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect('ldaps://yourADdomain.local');//I'm using LDAPS here

if (! $ldap_conn) {
        echo ("<p style='color: red;'>Couldn't connect to LDAP service</p>");
    }
else {    
        echo ("<p style='color: green;'>Connection to LDAP service successful!</p>");
     }
//The first step is to bind the administrator so that we can search user info
$ldapBindAdmin = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $adminDN, $adminPswd);

if ($ldapBindAdmin){
    echo ("<p style='color: green;'>Admin binding and authentication successful!!!</p>");

    $filter = '(sAMAccountName='.$username.')';
    $attributes = array("name", "telephonenumber", "mail", "samaccountname");
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $baseDN, $filter, $attributes);

    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_conn, $result);  
    $userDN = $entries[0]["name"][0];  
    echo ('<p style="color:green;">I have the user DN: '.$userDN.'</p>');

    //Okay, we're in! But now we need bind the user now that we have the user's DN
    $ldapBindUser = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $userDN, $userpass);

    if($ldapBindUser){
        echo ("<p style='color: green;'>User binding and authentication successful!!!</p>");        

        ldap_unbind($ldap_conn); // Clean up after ourselves.

    } else {
        echo ("<p style='color: red;'>There was a problem binding the user to LDAP :(</p>");   
    }     

} else {
    echo ("<p style='color: red;'>There was a problem binding the admin to LDAP :(</p>");   
} 
?>
```

Comment: All that work, and not enough upvotes. This is crazy useful.

Comment: I see this a lot: First logging in with a "functional account", query the data and then bind with the actual user logging in. In my opinion that is a bad practice - security wise. Having functional accounts whith passwords that virtually never change is bad. You could directly bind with the user logging in and then query in that session. I've never seen an AD where the user is not allowed to query its own data. For AD you have to bind with "userPrincipalName" or "domain\sAMAccountName" (full User DN should also work). Just my 2 cents. Still your solution is helpful, I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the info Chris. Your comment makes total sense. When I have a few hours to kill, I will try this out.

Comment: Ii also think that's bad practice but i'm clueless on how to perform a bind with samaccountname. domain\samaccountname is refused from openldap. How am i supposed to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Try user@domain on dn... It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You always need a DN to authenticate to a LDAP server. After that, you can perform a filter based in a specific attribute, like SamAccountName, but you need an LDAP user identified by a DN.

Comment: Must there always be a username or cn in the DN?  would it be possible to have a proxy user just to authenticate with and then search for the samAccountName and password?

Comment: Or is there a way to find the DN, particularly the username from a SamAccountName?

Comment: Normally, if you don't know the user DN, you have to authenticate with a valid LDAP user (as you say, the proxy user). You should follow this steps: 1.- authenticate with the proxy user, 2.- search the real user using SamAccountName in your filter, 3.- retrieve real user DN, 4.- Authenticate again using retrieved user DN and the password you have

Comment: I see.  Can I do a an anonymous bind and then search for the DN for the user with SamAccountName?

Comment: It depends of the LDAP server configuration, but theorically yes. Some LDAP administrators don't allow anonimous binds for security reasons, but you can try.

Comment: If SASL is configured at the directory server, it is possible to use the SASL authentication ID without using a distinguished name, but if not, the DN of a user and the password is required for the bind request.

Comment: Is there a particular password associated with the DN of a user? A DN password?  I now have the DN for the samAccountName, but am still getting Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials

Comment: The entry of your retrieved DN should be an account entry, eg. posixAccount, having a password attribute inside.

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP interface to AD requires that you bind using a DN. In order to authenticate a user, you must first find that user's DN — fortunately, you can find the DN by searching LDAP.

If you [configure AD to allow anonymous queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320528) (don't do this unless you are sure you're ok with the reduction in security), you can do

```
ldap_bind($connect, "", "")
$sr = ldap_search($connect, $base_dn, "(sAMAccountName=$username)")
```

And then retrieve that user's DN and proceed to rebind with the user's DN and password.

If you do *not* enable anonymous bind, then you use an application ID to do the initial search, like so:

```
ldap_bind($connect, "DN=LDAP_App,OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=com", "thePassword")
$sr = ldap_search($connect, $base_dn, "(sAMAccountName=$username)")
```

And then, just as above, retrieve that user's DN and proceed to rebind.